# Load balancing KEYs using GET via Redis

Tags: mysql, redis

my application currently using MySQL makes phone calls fetching information about the dialed numbers and the caller ID from the DB. I want to have a group where a list of caller IDs to be defined in Redis. Let's say 10 caller IDs. But for each dialing, I want to SELECT/GET the caller ID from redis server not just a random number. Is that possible with Redis? It's like load balancing from the list of Keys from redis to make sure all keys are given a fair chance to be used?

An example of the data set will be a phonebook which will be the key, and there will be say 10 phone numbers in that phonebook. I want to use those numbers for every unique dialing so all numbers in the phonebook are used evenly for dialing.

I can do that in MySQL by setting up an update field in the table but that's going to increate UPDATE's on MySQL. Is this something can easily be done with Redis? I can't seem to think of a logic on how to do that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to do it in Redis:

**ZSET**

You can track the usage frequency with the score of a zset entry. So when you fetch one out from Redis with lowest score, you increase its score by one.

The side benefit is you can easily see exactly how many times each element has been used.

**LIST**

If you're not bothered about tracking the usage in numbers. You can also do it with a Redis list. Just use `RPOPLPUSH source destination` from/to itself to achieve round robin load balancing effect. Basically it takes an element from the bottom and puts it back onto the top the queue, and returns you the value of the shuffled element, obviously.

The benefit is there is only one command to run and the operation is atomic.